# Styling DialogFragment dialog pre ice cream sandwich

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to style a `FragmentDialog` pre 4.0 so it appears as post 4.0.

I'm using `ActionBarSherlock` but I have to style it myself pre Ice Cream Sandwich.

I want to get following look:

[image]

But I'm getting this:

[image]

So basically I want it to not fill out the entire screen.

I've tried various styling but all without success and I've gotten to the point where I'm hoping there is some expert that can help me or guide me in the right direction

**My DialogFragment:**

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //TODO Style 2.3 to look like 4.0
        int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.Pre_Honeycomb_Holo_Dialog);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = null;
        int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_dialog_view, container);
        } else {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_dialog_view_content, container);
            this.getDialog().setTitle(R.string.info_dialog_title);
        }
...
```

Basically I'm building the title layout pre Ice Cream Sandwich but the content area is the same.

**My holo_dialog_style:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="Pre.Honeycomb.Holo.Dialog" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/panel_bg_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the many cases where libraries are your friend!

I'd suggest using [Styled Dialogs for Android](https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs).

It is able to produce dialogs looking like this:
[image: Example Dialogs]

To use it what you would need to do is first add it to Maven (if you are using it):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>eu.inmite.android.lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-styled-dialogs</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

or if you are using Ant, then you would want to just download the [latest jar](http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central-proxy&g=eu.inmite.android.lib&a=android-styled-dialogs&v=LATEST).

Now, you just need to setup your themeing to use the theme that you desire. Add the following to your application theme:

#### Holo Light

```
<item name="sdlDialogStyle">@style/DialogStyleLight.Custom</item>
```

#### Holo Dark

```
<item name="sdlDialogStyle">@style/DialogStyleDark.Custom</item>
```

You can also add the following style to allow you to customize as necessary:

```
<style name="DialogStyleLight.Custom">
    <!-- anything can be left out: -->
    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/dialog_title_text</item>
    <item name="titleSeparatorColor">@color/dialog_title_separator</item>
    <item name="messageTextColor">@color/dialog_message_text</item>
    <item name="buttonTextColor">@color/dialog_button_text</item>
    <item name="buttonSeparatorColor">@color/dialog_button_separator</item>
    <item name="buttonBackgroundColorNormal">@color/dialog_button_normal</item>
    <item name="buttonBackgroundColorPressed">@color/dialog_button_pressed</item>
    <item name="buttonBackgroundColorFocused">@color/dialog_button_focused</item>
    <item name="dialogBackground">@drawable/dialog_background</item>
</style>
```

Once you have that it's pretty easy to use:

## Dialog With a Simple Message and Close Button

```
SimpleDialogFragment.createBuilder(this, getSupportFragmentManager()).setMessage(R.string.message).show();
```

## Dialog With a Title, Message and Close Button

```
SimpleDialogFragment.createBuilder(this, getSupportFragmentManager()).setTitle(R.string.title).setMessage(R.string.message).show();
```

## Dialog With a Title, Message and Two Buttons

```
SimpleDialogFragment.createBuilder(this, getSupportFragmentManager()).setTitle(R.string.title).setMessage(R.string.message).setPositiveButtonText(R.string.positive_button).setNegativeButtonText(R.string.negative_button).show();
```

For additional examples, there's a couple [demos](https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs/tree/master/demo/src/eu/inmite/demo/dialogs) available as well.

Comment: This solved the problem but I had to include a library in order to make it work, also the HoloEverywhere library could have done the job as well. I rewarded you for putting thought and work into the answer but I still haven't decided if I want to take this direction.

Comment: I would definitely suggest utilizing the library. Libraries are your friend! Also, by doing this you help to ensure a consistent UI for all available Android devices (2.2+).

Comment: @timonvlad that is not how Dialogs would normally work in Android. I would suggest sticking with a similar look and feel to Android as a whole and simply using Text. Icons in and of themselves are not self-explanatory while text can be quite clear.

Comment: @David, y you are right about text... but my two buttons are just "ok" or "not"... so, two small icons are good enough....Can I change positive and negative button with drawable?

Comment: @timonvlad yeah, that's something that the library allows you to do. Take a look at the [JayneHatDialogFragment](https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs/blob/master/demo/src/eu/inmite/demo/dialogs/JayneHatDialogFragment.java) example of a custom dialog. Just apply the same concepts to your buttons.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid filling the whole screen you can use this code on the onStart method of the DialogFragment:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // safety check
    if (getDialog() == null)
        return;

    getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(width, height);

}
```

Set the desired width and height programmatically in the **getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(width, height);** method.

Then in the xml layout file that you are inflating (R.layout.info_dialog_view) set the width and height to match parent.